# List of foods for a low carb diet

Tags: diet

Hi I am currently on a low carb diet as I don't get much exercise and gained about 100 pounds since graduating high school due to side effects of a medication. I've lost about 35 so far without any exercise at all and am happy with this diet plan. I'm trying to do absolutely none (0 carbs) a day since, after some research, i found that this is the fastest way to lose weight on this diet. I have had success with eating very little carbs (20 or less) and would like to keep it that way. I guess I can have a little more if it fits the bill. Here is my question:

I have been eating the same thing for about 8 months now. (Meat, Cheese, Vegetables, black coffee, tea) but it's just becoming a chore just to get up and make myself something because I'm borderline disgusted with these plain dishes. When I go to the supermarket I pick up cheeses and meats and that's about it. I'm wondering if anyone else has experience with this diet plan, and has had good results, and what kind of foods you incorporate other than meat and cheese?

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't really an answerable question. You're either going to get a massive list of low carb foods or a lot of opinions of "Well, I eat this". If you can narrow your focus a bit, it could be nominated for reopening.

Comment: I am looking for the facts; low carb foods and recipes.

Comment: I already got some substantial "opinions" so you can close this if you want.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend vegan and gluten-free salads from [HomeJuice](http://homejuice.com.au/). Most salads are highly nutritious as they contain proteins, omega 3, proteins and fibre. Some raw vegetables and fruits also contain antioxidants like Vitamin C and Vitamin A that protects against health problems like cancer and heart disease.

You can also try juice detox. They are so refreshing and guaranteed to help you lose weight. I use http://homejuice.com.au/pages/melbourne-healthy-corporate-catering for my juice cleanse. This office catering helps maintain the healthy lifestyle even when I'm at work.

Answer (score 1):

Nuts have a minimal amount of carbs, however, it is very easy to overeat them, so you will want to carefully control portions. When I feel like including healthy carbs, I eat brown rice. Eggs and avocados usually go well with brown rice too. And if it fits into your own diet plan, eating dark chocolate (>85%) wouldn't significantly set you back and hopefully help you in not losing your sanity while losing weight.

And if you can cook, I'm sure you can incorporate a near endless combination of vegetables and oils into your diet. Low sugar fruits such as strawberries will also do you good. The fiber from fruits and vegetables will also help to fill you, keep your diet balanced, and aid your digestive system. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your post! However post on this site generally have references. Adding those will result in the post following site guidelines. For any other questions consult the help center or ask here. Thank you!

Comment: It's funny that you mention overeating peanuts and such because I have had this problem before. Didn't think of low sugar fruits though. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to fix your problem is to experiment and basically learn to make less exciting food more so. So buying a load of ingredients and then looking for recipes to use them up is always good.

But for some ingredient ideas try [here](http://www.ruled.me/ketogenic-diet-food-list/)

For specific recipes try places like [this](http://www.ruled.me/keto-recipes/)

I have been told low carb pizzas with a base made of cauliflower or sometimes chicken can be great. The toppings obviously easy to fill with low carb diets!

Hope that helps